# Having issues displaying react app on nginx server at domain

Tags: reactjs, linux, nginx

I'm trying to add a react app that will be displaying at `mydomain.com/react-app`. I'm pretty new to nginx and this is my first go at hosting a site on a Linux server. The site `mydomain.com` has existed on this server for some time and I built another part of the site using react and would like to host it at `/react-app`. This is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/react-app`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    location /react-app {
        alias /var/www/react-app/build/;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /build/index.html;
    }
}
```

I'm able to serve and visit the site at the IP location `0.0.0.0/react-app` but not `mydomain.com/react-app`. I just get a 404 nginx error when I visit that address.

Answer (score 1):

If your server app running for example on port 3500:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mydomain.com/ www.mydomain.com/;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3500;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay ill try that. Should the proxy_pass be the localhost the react app is running? And to get the path to work properly should it be location /react-app? Thanks!